# Visual Studio Code debug python script with ampersand in file path

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and debugging a python script.  I'm in a conda environment.  I start debugging, and at each line of execution, I get an error like this:

```
Unable to open 'filename.py': File not found (file:///s:/path/word&amp;morewords/etcetc/filename.py).
```

To be clear, this file that VS cannot find is the very same .py file that I have open in VS and am debugging.

It appears that where the ampersand occurs, it looks for "`&amp;`" instead of just "&".  But the debugger works, insofar as it evaluates lines and gives results.  But at each line step, the error pops open again.  Changing the file path isn't really an option.

The actual path is:

```
s:/path/word&morewords/etcetc/filename.py
```

How can I make this error not happen?

Also, the line that is being executed is not highlighted when I am running the debugger.  So, I have no idea where I am unless I keep track.  Perhaps these issues are related, but I am not sure.

Comment: Looks like a bug in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). You could [report it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: Where is your file located and what is being called?  A file can't just be unable to open, something must be trying to open it.  Where is the error occurring, what is the stack trace.  You need to include a lot more info for anyone to begin to answer this.

Comment: BTW &amp is a legal escape for ampersand.

Comment: @JamieMarshall - It's located in a path named like what I called it above.  The file is open in VS.  It's the same file that I'm debugging.  VS Code doesn't really give me any more information about it.  I cannot find to where VS is looking when it finds the file path that it then tells me it cannot open.  If I could look inside the debugger, then I'm sure I could fix it.

Comment: @Jimmy, there's a lot more going on here, its hard to get into unless you include a more complete code example.  The escapes in for instance in your file path look off to me, but I can't begin to answer this without more.  I use MS products to write python, and have debugged a lot in VS and VS Code.   How does it "pop" on each line?  I think you've got some stuff mixed up here.  Impossible to sort out as is.

Comment: @JamieMarshall, A box opens in the bottom-left of VS Code that says unable to open "filename.py" and then it lists that filepath with the &amp; rather than &.  Even if it's a valid escape for an ampersand, the file exists and is already opened in one sense in VS, so I was thinking that the debugger is taking the &amp; literally, in which case it wouldn't find it.  But I have no idea how to edit what it's looking for.  If I open the launch.json file, I see for "program" it says "${file}" and I'm thinking I could somehow edit that to be a file and path with a simple &.

Comment: Hmm. have you read through [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).  Can you confirm if your debugger is set to integrated terminal, and if so, is the file your debugging in your sys or user path?  Is your pythonPath variable for the debugger set so it can see the interpreter from the file you're trying to debug?

Comment: Also, not sure what OS in your in, but i'd avoid ampersands in a file name if at all possible.  They can have different encodings in other OS's which is a real pickle because any file system will read the file name before the file contents and won't know how to treat that file.

Comment: @JamieMarshall Yes, it is set to integrated terminal.  The file I am debugging is not in sys.path or in my user path (though the user path is less clear to me).  It seems that it can see the interpreter just fine, since it can execute the script in the file.  It just gives this error every time I run a line or advance to the next line.

Comment: It's very likely a bug in the extension. Please open an issue.

Comment: Thanks all.  I opened an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been verified as a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2620).